# React: oneOfType usage

Tags: reactjs

I see that another developer is using **oneOfType** like this:

```
size: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object]).isRequired,
```

It doesn't seem right to me. The way I understand **oneOfType** is that the prop should be one of a specified set of types like the example bellow:

```
size: PropTypes.oneOfType([
PropTypes.object,
PropTypes.number
]).isRequired,
```

However,

```
size: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object]).isRequired,
```

doesn't throw any linting errors and everything seems to be working fine.

Can I leave it as it is?

Comment: I don't see any harm in it from a code perspective, it's an odd code style but perhaps they expect the available types to grow in future, or it previously had additional options that have been removed and this was simply not tidied up.

Answer (score 0):

`oneOfType` is to consider one of some types will be valid

```
size: PropTypes.oneOfType([
PropTypes.object,
PropTypes.number
]).isRequired,
```

The above `oneOfType` means `size` can be `object` or `number`. And `isRequired` is to make sure you pass `size` value instead of leaving it empty.

---

```
size: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object]).isRequired,
```

With the above condition, `size` can be `object` *only* (no other types). And it's totally fine.

You also can consider changing the above condition to the below one which has the same goal.

```
size: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
```